# Ruby Block Variable not defined error in one line, but works on do..end block

Tags: ruby, rails-console, pry

I don't know how to explain this more, I'm open to suggestions.

Here is an example:

```
User.last.orders.detect { |user_order| user_order.query.id == 107 }
```

This doesn't work;

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method ` user_order' for main:Object
from (pry):51:in `block in <main>'
```

But this works:

```
User.last.orders.detect do |user_order|
  user_order.query.id == 107
end
```

This is just a simple example. I really don't understand why this happens. Thanks!

Comment: As pointed out below, it's likely a whitespace issue with your code. Otherwise, the code looks fine.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have an additional "non-breaking space" between the pipe and `user_order`, that's why the message says:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method ` user_order' for
>   main:Object

Your actual variable is " user_order" not "user_order".

This commonly happens when pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd> at the same time (on OSX), that's common when opening curly braces for "inline" blocks in Ruby.

Comment: "`user_order` not `user_order`" - wat? these are the same, no?

Comment: SO strips whitespace it views as un-necessary. Took me a minute to see as well, but if you look at the original error message things become more obvious when you're looking for a leading whitespace char in the variable name

Comment: @SimpleLime: ah, indeed. Yes, must be some unusual unicode whitespace in the source code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : In such cases, it helps looking at the code with a hex editor. This helps to identify the culprit.